# Excel VBA Use Offset to Move To Next Row

Tags: vba, excel

I want to place results in successive rows using the offset property if possible.

Line 9 is where I am having trouble getting the correct syntax.

```
Set startcell2 = Worksheets("Duplicates").Cells(1, 1)

rs.Open "Select dmdrawno From webprddt1.drawmstrp Where dmdrawno = '" & dwgno & "'", oConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

If Not rs.EOF Then
    'addnewrecord = False
Else
    startcell2.Value = dwgno
    startcell2.Offset(1, 0)
    addnewrecord = False

End If

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Look into CopyFromRecordset method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copyfromrecordset-method-excel

Comment: Either you want to place a value, in that case use `startcell2.Offset(1, 0) = "Your Value` , or `Set` a range, then use `Set RangeName = startcell2.Offset(1, 0)`.

Comment: `startcell2.Offset(1, 0).Value = rs.Fields(1).Value` since rs only returns one field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 9 should read

```
Set startcell2 = startcell2.Offset(1, 0)
```

and then preferably be in a loop where you read the records